# Chrome Mute Tab Function

Tags: google-chrome, audio, tabs, mute

There are many other threads about this, all that list outdated information. The flag `chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting` no longer exists, and extensions posted by other users no longer work.

I have 2 tabs of my game open, being on the same website. Right clicking and muting one of the tabs causes both tabs to mute. Is there a way to mute only 1 instance of a tab?

Due to both instances having to be loaded on the same account, I cannot load the tab on a different browser.

Comment: Check [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044761/how-to-mute-all-sound-in-a-page-with-js/14045788) answers from SO.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I wasn't clear. It's not my game, but a game I play - I have very little JS knowledge sorry.

Comment: With your *little JS knowledge* you can just copy any of those code and paste it in chrome dev console. To open chrome dev console, press `F12` it will open a small window, now under `console` tab `paste` the code. If you could share the link to that game, i will test from my side and tell you.